How to give permission to script to access drive when run by shared user
Document bound script when run by shared user gives an error. Script is for creating a pdf of the document in owners folder which is also shared with the user. Script is as under -
const pdfFolderId   = "folder_id"; folder shared with user where pdf is tobe created

function onOpen(e){
  menu();
}

function menu(){
 DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Save as')
  .addItem('PDF', 'createPDF')
  .addToUi();
}

function createPDF(){
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(pdfFolderId);
  var file = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var files = pdfFolder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (files.hasNext()){
    var pdf = files.next();
    pdf.setTrashed(true);
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('File Deleted.')
  }
  const blobPDF = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(fileName);
  return pdfFile;
  // Logger.log(fileName);

}

It gives an error "Exception: Access denied: DriveApp."
I added oauthScopes to JSON then also same problem is there. the scope is as below -
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
    
  ]
}

Please help me in solving this problem.

In Google Drive, users can only create files in their folders and Shared Drive if they have "Can create and add files, can create folders" permissions.
If you have access to a Shared Drive and the users have the required permissions to create a file in a Shared Drive, your script has to use the Advanced Drive Service instead of the Drive Service (Class DriveApp).
Use an installable trigger created by the folder owner to create/add files to them. One way is to ask them to use a Google Form and set an on-form-submit trigger to create the file instead of using a custom menu.

Can you please describe how to use Advanced Drive Service. Since I am new to appscript I need detailed help. Please......
